# Getting warning for Promise Rejection when upgrading from expo 32 to expo 33

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

While loading images, I am getting warning for not handling promise rejection after upgrading to expo SDK 33 from 32. Did anybody got this type of warning after upgrading to expo 33.

Though I am able to display them, but as there are many images used in the app. There are plenty of warning piled up.

Following is the warning:

> promise rejection: Error: Downloaded file for asset
>   'icon-back-white.png' Located at
>   xxxx/assets/src/assets/images/icon-back-white@3x.png?platform=android&hash=ae2c2f499f2345b43bc93152d5552b7e?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fxyz%2FDocuments%2Fmy_workspace%2Fuserapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js failed MD5 integrity check]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can run `expo optimize`

Answer (score 0):

run `expo optimize` command. Here's a very good blog on [Image Compression with Expo CLI](https://blog.expo.io/image-compression-with-expo-cli-d32d15cc8b73)